# Why QGIS installs QT related plugins?

Tags: qgis, qt, qt-designer

I dread installing `QGIS` because this additionally always installs `QT Assistant`, `QT Designer`, `QT Linguist`. Any reason behind it?

I don't use any plugins but `sudo apt install qgis` forces to install mentioned `QT` programs.

Comment: because you need them to develop plugins - is there a downside to installing them?

Comment: The downside is many packages that installed with QGIS, I don't want to pollute system